# What is the meaning of ケタ外れ in this situation..?

Tags: translation, meaning, expressions, adjectives

I have a sentence which says,

> 2030年、日本が迎えるのはケタ外れの「ひとりさま社会」。

The dictionary says the word means; incredible, extraordinary, exceptional or phenomenal, but it doesn't really make sense when translated into English. What does ケタ外れ mean here? What does it imply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ケタ is 桁 which in this context can be understood as "standard/norm" or "reference frame" and 外れ means something like it "falls out of the reference frame" — like when people use 120%.

You can see how in some contexts this could be translated the way you listed (incredible, extraordinary, exceptional or phenomenal), but here it should probably be translated in a more neutral tone.

Comment: Do you think in this context, it could mean something close to “extreme compared to now”? I assume the author is saying that the number of people living alone is going to increase dramatically.

Comment: Technically speaking, ケタ (桁) means "digit places" here. It comes from rods that hold beads in the abacus. So 桁外れ means that some amount has a different order of magnitude than others.